# Unable to open the marketplace in STS4 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, sts

I've a windows 10 64 bit machine on which I've set up the java 8. So for one of the project I'm trying to set up the STS4 on machine but unfortunately couldn't get through.

Need assistance on it.

Whereas I tried various below options

1. Change in configuration file
   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
2. Change the proxy setting
3. Change the network connection to each of the option i.e. Direct, Manual etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for above post but couldn't stop myself by sharing my experience.

Yesterday I tried all the options given on various sites/blogs. Post that I restarted my machine several times also. But no luck.

And today after fading up very first I posted the problem on stack overflow & magic turns out.

!!!Now marketplace is got without any error. I have all the changes as it is. Not sure what makes to go through the problem.

Comment: *"I don't know how to solve the issue"* is entirely unhelpful.